# Javascript Light Box Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

Within my webpage here: www.easenhall.org.uk/gallery.html
I have this error:
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at gallery.html:54

I downloaded this code from a website so Im not very good at coding in Java Script, if you click on an image on the webpage the image/lightbox moves around to begin with then it stops. Would fixing this error solve this if not how would I correct it?
Here is the java script code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function($){
            var addToAll = true;
            var gallery = true;
            var titlePosition = 'inside';
            $(addToAll ? 'img' : 'img.fancybox').each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                //var title = $this.attr('title');
                var src = $this.attr('data-big') || $this.attr('src');
                var a = $('<a href="#" class="fancybox"></a>').attr('href', src);//.attr('title', title);
                $this.wrap(a);
            });
            if (gallery)
                $('a.fancybox').attr('rel', 'fancyboxgallery');
            $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
                //titlePosition: titlePosition
            });
        });
        $.noConflict();
        var lightboxOnResize = function lightboxOnResize() {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
        $('a[rel="lightbox"]')
            .removeProp('rel')
            .addClass('lightboxRemoved');
    } else {
        $('a.lightboxRemoved').prop('rel', 'lightbox');
    }
}
        $(document).ready(lightboxOnResize);
        $(window).resize(lightboxOnResize);
    </script>
```

The error part is this line here:

```
$(document).ready(lightboxOnResize);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a function inside of a different scope. Look at the $(function($) {...}); It creates a closure and outside functions cannot access the ones defined inside of the closure!

Simplest solution is to move your

```
$(document).ready(lightboxOnResize);
$(window).resize(lightboxOnResize);
```

statements into the closure.

Comment: OP needs to place their additional code inside the closure. Enclosing `jQuery` code in closures is default and recommended way in WordPress, mainly because sometimes using different jQuery versions on the same page has to be possible. See [`here`](https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/).

Comment: Thanks it has fixed the error message but the lightbox still jumps when it fist loads. Is there anything else I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Update your function, hope this helps you ?

```
var lightboxOnResize = (function () {

 });

$(document).ready(lightboxOnResize);
```